# When was the last time that 19 Republican senators cross-the-aisle with a unified Democratic party on anything not bipartisan?

Tags: united-states, president, senate, impeachment

To impeach Trump, you would need a super-majority (2/3). That means 67 total senators. There are 46 Democrats, and 2 Independents. Assuming you had 100% support of the Democrats and Independents, you would still require 19 Republican Senators to side with the Democrats and Independents.

When was the last time 19 Republican senators crossed the aisle (ie, on a partisan issue) and joined or largely unified Democratic party?

Comment: Your new title seems to be missing a verb. Unless "cross-the-aisle" is a verb (which I guess it could be; as Bill Watterson famously wrote, "verbing weirds language"), in which case it seems to be in the wrong tense (or be missing an auxiliary).

Comment: "cross-the-aisle" seems to be a verb, but it should be used in the past tense here, since it is referring to actions that may or may not have occurred in history: "crossed-the-aisle".

Comment: Isn't the definition of "bi-partisan" something where one side crosses the aisle to join with the other side?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Violence Against Women Reauthorization Act of 2013](https://www.congress.gov/bill/113th-congress/senate-bill/47/text) passed the Senate with a vote of 78-22. You can see [from the floor debate before the vote](https://www.congress.gov/congressional-record/2013/02/12/senate-section/article/S613-2) that this was contentious:

> The Senator from Oklahoma has consistently voted against VAWA. That 
>   is his right. But we should not make the programs more difficult for 
>   law enforcement and victims because he does not support them. This is 
>   not the right way to reduce government--by setting up government 
>   mandates that law enforcement cannot meet and then cutting their 
>   assistance funding when they cannot. I do not believe this one-size-
>   fits-all mandate from Washington to our states is the right way to go.
>
> [...]
>
> The people who oppose it oppose it on the grounds they 
>   might not get as much money unless they actually keep a woman from 
>   getting raped twice--once by the system we set up and once by their 
>   attacker.
>
> [...]
>
> Mr. LEE. Madam President, today I would like to address a provision 
>   of the Violence Against Women Act, S. 47, that is of great concern. 
>   Title IX of VAWA provides tribal courts with special jurisdiction over 
>   non-Indians who are charged with crimes of domestic violence.
>
> [...]